# Which machine learning or AI algorithm is best for this scenario?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a program which takes 3 inputs (a, b, c) and produces 2 outputs (x, y).  The program is deterministic; if I give the same inputs, I'm guaranteed to get the same outputs.

My objective is find the best combination of (a, b, c) which results in maximizing x, while minimizing y. Increases in y will generally lead to an increase in x, but there is a cap which y cannot exceed and a x cannot fall below.

Which machine learning or AI algorithms should I start looking into as a possible solution to solving this problem?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with statistics and has more to do with optimization. This would probably get better answers at https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: **ML** and **AI** is effective and useful, when the problem is **non-deterministic and complex**. If the problem is definitely deterministic, try to establish a **mathematical linear relationship** between the input and output. Somewhat like, if A = B = C = 1 then x = y = 1.
if A > B and B < C then x = 2(A+B+C) y = -2(A+B+C) and so on. Using ML and AI for a completely linear problem would be like **crushing a paper in a metal crusher**. https://hbr.org/2021/02/when-should-you-use-ai-to-solve-problems

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This goal is fundamentally flawed. If you maximize $x$, you might not be able to minimize $y$, and if you minimize $y$, you might not be able to maximize $x$. Do you want to maximize $x$ such that $y$ is no greater than some value? Do you want to minimize $y$ such that $x$ is no less than some value? // If my suspicion is correct, then this is a problem in decision theory and absolutely within the scope of Cross Validated.

Comment: @Dave Yes, you are correct.  There is a cap for y that I cannot exceed.  I'll update the question to add that condition.

Comment: Are the $x$ and $y$ something like sensitivity and specificity of a classifier?

Comment: [This paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/004017008000000541) strikes me as relevant, though not an exact solution to your problem.